# Avoid running script when refreshing page in Django

Tags: python, django

I am running my external python script using submit button on my web page

**script.py:**

```
def function():
    print('test it')
```

**views.py**

```
from script import function
def func_view(request):
    if request .method == 'POST':
        function()
    return render('my.html',{'run_script':function})
```

Problem:
when I am opening `my` page, program is running, it's not waiting until I will click this button.

additionally: when I add in my `if request loop` File input, after refreshing web page , Django is adding same file again.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved using redirect to this function:

```
from script import function
def func_view(request):
    if request .method == 'POST':
        function()
        return redirect(func_view)
    return render('my.html',{'run_script':function})
```